# Django suit menu without child

Tags: django, django-admin, django-suit

I want to create a custom menu in django-suit that attached to a model without any child. I have done it for django users like this:

```
       {'label': 'Users', 'url': '/admin/auth/user/', 'icon': 'icon-user'},
```

But the hard-coded url may not always valid. Is there any better approach to do it without hard-coded url?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
{'label': 'Users', 'url': 'auth.user', 'icon':'icon-user'},
```

Comment: No. It creates a child. But I don't want to create any child of menu. Anyway thnx for your answer.